# PowerShell - Remove text from output

Tags: powershell, wsh

I am running this command to find out when a license will expire on a set of servers:

```
cscript c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs $server /xpr | Add-Content $LogFile
```

The output that is written to the LogFile looks like this:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Windows Server(R), ServerStandard edition:
    Volume activation will expire 6/15/2014 1:12:33 PM
```

How can I remove the first three line in the output text file?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the nologo directive.

`cscript //nologo c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs $server /xpr | Add-Content $LogFile`

Comment: Wow, it was that easy.  Thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: @user3120098 You can save it as the default command-line option by running `cscript //NoLogo //s`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use //nologo. This option strips out the windows stuff and leaves you just the info you're looking for. If you still want a more precise output, try using regular expressions. Your ending command should look like this:

```
cscript //nologo c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs $server /xpr | Add-Content $LogFile
```